# Slicing data block by block using Python

Tags: python, line, block, slice

everyone, I have a big file in the format given below. The data is in the "block" format. one "block" containing three rows: the time T, the user U, and the content W. 
for example, this is a block:

```
T   2009-06-11 21:57:23
U   tracygazzard
W   David Letterman is good man
```

Since i will only using the block containing specific key word. I slice the data from the original massive data block by block, rather than dump the whole data into memory. each time read in one block, and if the row of content containing the word of "bike", write this block into disk.

you can use the following two blocks to test your script.

```
T   2009-06-11 21:57:23
U   tracygazzard
W   David Letterman is good man

T   2009-06-11 21:57:23
U   charilie
W   i want a bike
```

I have tried to do the work line by line:

```
data = open("OWS.txt", 'r')
output = open("result.txt", 'w')

for line in data:
    if line.find("bike")!= -1:
    output.write(line)
```

Comment: thank you， I have tried using for line in data:
    if line.find("bike")!= -1:
 output.write(line)

Comment: thus i can solve the problem line by line, but i don't know how to do it block by block. and you don't need to give all the code. just the key part.

Comment: Do the lines in each block actually start with `T`, `U` and `W`?

Comment: Yes. For this specific data. it's formatted in this way.

Comment: I have tried the script in the hyperlink before, however, it's not concise. But you can also refer to https://github.com/chengjun/python/blob/master/workshop%20of%20python/massive_data/simpleParseMain.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the format of your blocks is constant, you can use a list to hold a block, then see if `bike` is in that block:

```
data = open("OWS.txt", 'r')
output = open("result.txt", 'w')

chunk = []
for line in data:
    chunk.append(line)
    if line[0] == 'W':
        if 'bike' in str(chunk):
            for line in chunk:
                output.write(line)
        chunk = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
data = open("OWS.txt", 'r').read()   # Read the entire file into a string
output = open("result.txt", 'w')

for match in re.finditer(
    r"""(?mx)          # Verbose regex, ^ matches start of line
    ^T\s+(?P<T>.*)\s*  # Match first line
    ^U\s+(?P<U>.*)\s*  # Match second line
    ^W\s+(?P<W>.*)\s*  # Match third line""", 
    data):
        if "bike" in match.group("W"):
            output.write(match.group())  # outputs entire match
```

Comment: have you considered the issue of memory? # Read the entire file into a string

Comment: @FrankWANG: Well, how big are your files?

Comment: it's 26 G, although i can split it into smaller ones.